# Is there a API or method to automatically upload apprentice On the Job Hours (OJT) to the DOL system instead of manually entering it?

Tags: api, government, labor

Our HR department has to manually enter data for apprentice level employees who are participating in the apprenticeship program as part of the apprenticeship program rules.  Is there an API that our company's in-house developer can use to automatically have this information uploaded from our payroll to the Department of Labor system?